# Overflow error while trying to calculate Boltzmanns Equation and plot it on graph

Tags: python, python-3.x

On Second_factor it shows me an Overflow Error. Could someone suggest alternatives.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = []
NnN1 = []
n2i = 2
K = 1.38 * (10 ** -23)

for i in range(1, 101):
    n.append(i)
T = 100
for i in n:
    DE = -13.6 * (1 / (n[i] ** 2) - 1 / n2i)
    gn = 2 * (n[i] ** 2)
    Dg = gn / n2i
    Second_factor  =  pow(2.71828 , DE/(K*T))
    Nn = Dg * Second_factor
    NnN1.append(Nn)

print(NnN1)
```

Comment: use Decimal module to handle the results

Comment: I have to make a list and use the list in order to plot the graph, how will I be able to use it? Could you do a demonstration of the correct code ?

Answer (score 0):

a snippet for reproduction, nice!

Your problem is not with the code, but with your math, check for bugs. If you add a print statement, you will see that the value of `DE/(K*T)` is 2.4e+25. So you are raising 2.71 to the power of 24000000000000000000000000, hence the overflow.

Comment: I am doing a physics graph where i make a list and plot it using matplotlib.pyplot 
is there no way i can continue with the same value ?

Comment: With these formulas you are not doing a physics graph, you are doing a fantasy graph, with numbers that have 10**25 zeros! There is, however, one thing you could try - plot the logs. That is, compute log_Nn, which would be log(Dg) + log(Second_factor), which in turn would be log(2.7i) * DE/(K*T).